# Is the 'compose objects' API for Google Cloud Storage availabe through the C# client libraries?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I need to upload very large files (approaching hundreds of gigs).  I am planning to upload smaller parts (out-of-order and in parallel) and then use the Object Compose API to compose them into one large Object (hierarchically if necessary).  However, I cannot see any appropriate API in the C# client libraries (Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 2.4.0-beta03) which would do the same as the JSON API at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/compose.  Do I have to use the JSON API?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own question. As of this date, the source code (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet, commit 1b2de06f70e31382ef4d6de9062b30ce64dfb463) contains no meaningful mention of compose or concatenate except as a possible TODO comment.